# Trazendo janela Winform para frente

Tags: c#, winforms

Tem algumas partes da minha aplicação que precisa do retorno do usuário, como perguntando sobre se quer fazer atualização, ou na tela de ativação do sistema, porém as vezes essas telas, ou messagebox, ficam sem seleção, e ficam atrás da janela corrente. Preciso saber como deixar uma tela ou messagebox sobre todas as telas do programa, e talvez se possível, do windows todo, aguardando resposta do usuário, para ele ter que responder ao invés de continuar usando o sistema ou outro programa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**MessageBox**:

Por padrão as `MessageBox` sempre vão aparecer na frente de todas as outras janelas.

**Forms**:

Você pode mostrar os forms com [`ShowDialog()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx), isso vai impossibilitar o usuário de interagir com outros forms da mesma aplicação, até que o form atual seja fechado.

O método [`BringToFront()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront(v=vs.110).aspx) pode ser usado para colocar um form a frente dos outros da aplicação.

O método [`Activate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate(v=vs.110).aspx) faz basicamente a mesma coisa que o `BringToFront`, com o adicional de dar foco no form.

Quanto a colocar o form a frente de qualquer janela do sistema operacional, eu acho que não existe nada nativo, de qualquer forma, eu vou procurar mais sobre isso.

Apenas uma dica: usuários geralmente não gostam deste tipo de comportamento (pop-ups pulando na frente de qualquer janela).

Answer (score 0):

Para deixar a sua aplicação a frente de todas as outras no terminal, ou o form a frente de tudo coloque `this.TopMost = true`, desta forma irá deixar sempre esta aplicação a frente de **TUDO**. Ai para trabalhar com os forms utilize os metódos já indicados: `ShowDialog`, `BringToFront` ou `Activate`.

Answer (score -1):

Para isso tens de usar o formulário que queres em cima como `form.ShowDialog()`